# How can we get width and height of a cell in mxgraph after implying some scale and zoom on graph?

Tags: geometry, cell, scale, vertex, mxgraph

I'm trying to achieve an specific cell geometry width and height after implementing some scale and zoom on the graph(I want its new geometry attributes!).

Answer (score 0):

```
var state = graph.view.getState(cell);
console.log(state.width, state.height);
```

Comment: in this statements we get the same values before scaling! it seems that we must explicitly multiply these values with scale factor to get the right values.